# How can I position text in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For example:

```
write("First Last", True, align="right")
```

But with specific (x,y) coordinates

Comment: It uses the current turtle position, so you will have to position your turtle at x, y first.

Comment: Use one of the [Turtle motion - Move and draw](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#overview-of-available-turtle-and-screen-methods)

Answer (score 2):

Along with using a command like `setposition()` aka `goto()`, `setx()` or `sety()` to position your turtle before you call `write()`, the `move` parameter to `write()`, which you set to `True`, doesn't do much when right aligning a *left to right* language like English, so you might as well leave it out:

```
setposition(100, 150)

write("First Last", align="right")
```

This will write the text `"First Last"`, right aligned to the point `(100, 150)`.  I.e. the *end* of the text will fall at that position.

Answer (score 1):

Before writing the text to the screen, you can hide the turtle, penup and move the turtle to a specific position.

```
import turtle
import datetime

turt = turtle.Turtle()

today = datetime.datetime.now()
turt.hideturtle()
turt.penup()
#Take the turtle to left edge of the screen
turt.backward((turt.getscreen().window_width() / 2) - 10)
message = "Hello Turtle! \nToday is " + today.strftime("%A") + ', ' + today.strftime("%d") \
           + ', ' + today.strftime("%B") + ', ' + today.strftime("%Y") 

turt.write(message,move=False, font=('monaco',30,'bold'),align='left')
turtle.done()
```